# Help evaluating the series ${n/2 + k}\choose{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I'm trying to find an alternate way of writing this series here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_of_2cos(2pi/n)

I feel like I could do it if I can come up with a nice formula for:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {{\lfloor{\frac{n + k}{2}}\rfloor}\choose{k}}x^k$$

Any ideas?